# SCSS is being compiled to CSS but changes are not being shown in the browser

Tags: css, sass

New to SASS and have set up a preprocessor through Scout App. When I click save, Scout informs me the updates have been made and changes are shown in the CSS but the changes won't display on my browser.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> The Green Keeper </title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Yesteryear" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href= "css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
    <body>
      <header>
        <h1> The Green Keeper </h1>
      </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

scss

```
// VARIABLES -------------------------------------->

$color-primary: #E5E5E5;

$font-stack-primary: 'Yesteryear', cursive;
$font-stack-secondary: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

// BASE -------------------------------------->

h1 {
  font-family: $font-stack-primary;
  color: $color-primary;
}
```

Comment: try opening in incognito mode once please or some other browser

Comment: Tried both, it just shows the H1 in the standard black font.

Comment: can you show the compiled CSS?

Comment: Does anything change when you update the styles? Is the CSS file linked correctly?

Comment: can you show the live example ?

Comment: Compiled css: h1{font-family:"Yesteryear",cursive;color:#E5E5E5}        
Scout recognizes the changes but they do not appear in browser.   
Live example as how the browser looks? It just says The Green Keeper in the standard H1 font and size.

Comment: @SeanDaniel Are you sure the CSS file is loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Old browser caching scenario**

Try to add `?v=2` to the href attribute of the css file. Total result:

```
<link href="css/style.css?v=2" rel="stylesheet">
```

Sometimes the browser uses the old cached version of the same file, because it tries to optimize time loading of the page, by saving referenced files by their names. With the mentioned trick you can force the browser to reload the new version of the updated file. Some call it version control with cachebusting.

Note: you should always increase the number, in order to see the most updated version immediately. With most module bundlers like webpack or gulp, you can have an automated process that generate this added query string value, computed by hashing the content (better for production, but can be slower for development), or by generating a random number per each compilation (better for development).

However, if you choose to do nothing, the browser will follow the 'cache-control' header of the file, that the server has generated. Some servers have a default value of: `max-age=86400`, meaning it will stop using the cached version after 24 hours, and will fetch a newer version to be stored again into the cache.

*This wasn't the actual solution in this particular case, but it might be the reason for someone else.

**Reference mismatch**

The solution for this specific problem was referencing an incorrect path inside the `href` attribute. We found an error while checking the 'Network' tab inside the browser's devtools: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND". The solution was to reference the correct path:

```
<link href= "output/style.css?v=2" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Added ?v=2 and still no luck.

Comment: Did you save the file? What happens if you open it with notepad?

Comment: You might try it with a random number rather than "2" - or clearing the cache, trying another browser or another computer.  If that doesn't work then it's likely something else.  Could be internal caching as well on the server side.  Adding a "salt" (an internal random element to the CSS could test that as well.

Comment: Yes it was saved, what am exactly opening in Notepad? Is text-edit the equivalent in Mac? Added 3 and 4 separately and it didn't work and tried another browser with the same problem. Tried clearing the cache and not sure if I did it properly on atom. Typed atom --safe to the command line and it wasn't found.

Comment: Try any regular text editor, like TextEdit. Open the "style.css" file, and check if you see the compiled version of the CSS, so we can know where is the problem.

Comment: `/* line 10, /Users/Grootsy/Desktop/The Green Keeper/input/style.scss */
h1 {
  font-family: "Yesteryear", cursive;
  color: #E5E5E5;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=../output/style.map */`

Comment: Now open devtools of chrome, by pressing F12. Go to "Sources" tab, and look for the "style.css" file. What do you see?

Comment: I only see the index.html file

Comment: Look at the left pane, there you can look for the files inside your domain.

Comment: Yes, the left pane only shows index.html. My style.css file is not there.

Comment: Go to the "Network" tab, and press F5. Do you see any errors?

Comment: css/style.css?v=2:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: That means the file is not in the right path. Your complied file should be in a 'css' directory. Or change the path in the 'href' attribute (href="style.css").

Comment: Thank you, I had a directory called output but this whole time had the wrong directory name linking the stylesheet. `<link href= "css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">` and now  `<link href= "output/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: @TechWisdom I know this answer has been accepted, but our comments are really what the problem was - not caching. Can you update the answer to reflect that the OP was linking the CSS file incorrectly?

Comment: @disinfor Done. I added this as the final solution, while leaving the other option for anyone else who run into the same situation, to consider.

Answer (score 0):

@JC Nolan  "You might try it with a random number rather than "2" - or clearing the cache, trying another browser or another computer. If that doesn't work then it's likely something else. Could be internal caching as well on the server side. Adding a "salt" (an internal random element to the CSS could test that as well."

for me, clearing browser cache worked!